# How to create a server alias for joomla

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla3.0

I have a multilanguage website in joomla. The FaLang component creates the following URLs:
www.myDutchDomain.nl/nl/

www.myDutchDomain.nl/en/

www.myDutchDomain.nl/de/

I have 2 other URLs which should redirect to English and German URL:

www.myEnglishDomain.eu >> www.myDutchDomain.nl/en/

www.myGermanDomain.de >> www.myDutchDomain.nl/de/

After redirect I want to see myEnglishDomain and myGermandomain in URL. If I'm not mistaken it's called server alias. 
How can I create a server alias for this purpose?

Comment: I'm not familiar with joomla, but do you have access to url rewriting such as within web.config or .htaccess ?

Comment: @Radderz yes I can access and edit .htacces, but not web.config

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use mod rewrite to solve this by adding lines to your .htaccess file, allowing anything on your country domains 'www.myEnglishDomain.eu/*{wildcard}*' to be rewritten to the country path '/en/*{wildcard}*'.

First you must make sure that the bindings for each domain are pointing to this website.

Then add the following lines to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myEnglishDomain.eu$[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myGermanDomain.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de/$1 [L]
```

If you need the domain within the browser to update to myDutchDomain.nl, then doing the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myEnglishDomain.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myDutchDomain.nl/en/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myGermanDomain.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myDutchDomain.nl/de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For further help, here is a mod rewrite cheat sheet: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/

**Disclaimer: I have not been able to test the above rules, please let me know if this contains syntax or other errors so to maintain an accurate reference for other people.**